# AssemblyInfo.vb change Log4NetAssembly1.exe.log4net path to user's local folder

Tags: vb.net, log4net, local, .net-assembly

My vb.net project used for different users, I am lost in how to set the Log4NetAssembly1.exe.log4net file path to user's local folder in AssemblyInfo.vb.
The Log4NetAssembly1.exe.log4net file is located in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\DeskApp\DeskApp\Log4NetAssembly1.exe.log4net for each user.

I have tried to use the following way but it not work:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("DeskApp")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("ESRI")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("DeskApp")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © ESRI 2009")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")> 
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XMLConfigurator(ConfigFile:="${LOCALAPPDATA}\Temp\DeskApp\DeskApp\Log4NetAssembly1.exe.log4net", Watch:=True)>
```

I am using vs 2012, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried to put the log4net file in the same folder as AssemblyInfo.vb, and use:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XMLConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension:="log4net", Watch:=True)>
```

But it not take effect.

Comment: You can check if log4net is picking up the configuration by checking `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the config file is in the same folder as the .exe then you [don't need to specify an absolute path](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes):

> ConfigFile
>
> If specified, this is the filename of the configuration
>   file to use with the XmlConfigurator. This file path is relative to
>   the application base directory
>   (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).

If though the config file is in an unrelated directory, you will have to remove the assembly attribute and configure log4net at runtime, as otherwise the environment variables will not be evaluated:

```
Dim filePath as String = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
                                    (Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), 
                        "Temp\DeskApp\DeskApp\Log4NetAssembly1.exe.log4net")

Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(filePath)

If fileInfo.Exists = False Then
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("Can't locate the log4net config file")
End If

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fileInfo)
```

Comment: Hello stuartd, I tried to put them in the same folder and update the AssemblyInfo.vb as the example, but no effect. I have edited my question, thank you!

Comment: Hi stuartd, so sorry for the late reply. I have successfully configure log4net at runtime. Thanks a lot.